# Completely locking down Windows 7 using Python 3.2?

Tags: winapi, windows-7, python-3.x, block, pywin32

This might be a more difficult question since I don't even know how to do it outside of Python...

I want to write a terminal program that completely locks up my PC until a password is entered. In the locked state no one should be able to do *anything outside* the terminal. In it, the user may rampage and write silly commands, but he should not be able to switch windows, click outside of it, open the task manager, open the menu with *Ctrl + Alt Gr + Del* and so on.

While searching for a way to accomplish this I've thought of two approaches that Python is also able to do:

- Modifying the registry **->** can disable task manager and some other functions, but not the app switcher neither the menu
- Task-killing explorer.exe and dwm.exe **->** killing explorer.exe just removed the taskbar, killing dwm.exe seems like the right way, but as it's the window manager it automatically boots up itself again as soon as it gets killed

I know this is a kind of weird question and doesn't contain *any* code snippet, but the front-end is no problem and as said I don't even got a working approach for the back-end.

Comment: You could create a new, blank desktop and switch to it. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682573%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: That looks like a good approach. Accordings to the msdn the ScreenSaver-Desktop should work for my needs and pywin32 can access said API calls using the win32service module, according to the provided Documentation. I'll try it out and see how much I can get to work, as it also states that Python 3.x support is still experimental.

Answer (score -1):

1. write a while loop
2. Into the while loop write the command to taskkill dwm.exe

It's a poor solution, but the only one I know.

Regards!